# WordPress Themes API

Tags: api, wordpress, themes

When studying the source of /wp-admin/theme-install.php?tab=search, I discovered the theme directory you get inside WordPress Admin -> Add New Themes is generated from an API call to http://api.wordpress.org/themes/info/1.0/

Unfortunately, there is no documentation for this yet.

I tried picking apart /wp-admin/theme-install.php?tab=search to regenerate the theme listing outside of WP Admin, but have not been able to do so.

Has anyone does this?

Can someone figure out how to get that theme listing/directory outside of the Admin area?

Comment: Interesting question. Can you tell us more about what you're trying to do with the theme listing outside of WP Admin?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
/** Sets up the WordPress Environment. */
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

/** WordPress Theme Administration API */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/theme.php');

$themes = get_themes();
var_dump($themes);

?>
```